# Ubuntu and Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my hard disk and have Windows 7 still there

I am using a method at [Pen Drive Linux](http://pendrivelinux.com) where i can get a iso of ubuntu, and use the program to install it onto my usb, then install it like you would on a cd with the iso. So is there a way I can do this while still having Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You have Win7 installed and want to install ubuntu onto a usb stick, without harming your Windows? Did I understand that correctly? If so, that shouldn't be a problem.

The only thing you should have two looks on is not to overwrite the bootloader on your hard drive, but the one on your usb stick during installation.

Comment: I want to use the program on PDL to install the iso onto the usb, and then boot from the usb, to install it on my system, without harming windows

Comment: Okay, now I am confused ;)

Comment: i will just try and see what happens.